# FQL: stream table does not return others links

Tags: stream, hyperlink, facebook-fql

I'm attempting to get all posts of my company page through a FQL query.

- Normal posts by others are returned ok (posts containing only text).
- Posts by the company itself that contains links is returned ok.

BUT:

- Posts by others then the company itself, that contains a link is not returned from the stream table.

Does anyone have any idea why?

My simple FQL query:

```
SELECT 
    post_id, type, actor_id, message
FROM stream 
WHERE 
    source_id = 123
    AND updated_time >= 123
ORDER BY updated_time
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Is the result same when you execute your query on [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) FQL tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get Links using another FQL query. Use the [Link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link) table for this instead.